# Click on button not working after pop up shown?

Tags: android, popupwindow

When popup is shown click on button not working on which pop window is shown?

```
private void initiatePopupWindow(ScrollView sv) {
    try {


       if(popOpened){

            pwindo.dismiss();
        popOpened = false;
       }
        else{

        pwindo = new PopupWindow(sv, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 800, true);
        pwindo.showAsDropDown(filterButton,30,30);
         popOpened = true;
      }


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

filterButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            System.out.println("this is click of filter button:::");



            if (filterProduct.isEmpty()) {

                GetFilterWS task = new GetFilterWS();
                task.execute();
            } else {
                initiatePopupWindow(sv);

            }

        }
    });
```

System.out.println message not printing when popup window is shown.

Comment: show relevant part of code

Comment: Button click is not working on which this method is called ?

Comment: how you know button click not working?

Comment: System.out.println("this is click of filter button:::"); this is not printing.

Comment: use Log.d("KEY","this is click of filter button") instead of System.out.println for example,  because in old Android versions or Custom Roms it may be not available

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried PopupWndow.setOutsideTouchable(true);